# The color difference between the "answered" checkmark and the "unanswered" one is barely discernable

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Color scheme and the colorblind](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2955/color-scheme-and-the-colorblind)

(On a laptop, to someone who is red/green color-blind.)

The "answered" checkmark should take on a distinctly different color from the up/down arrows, to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate of the other one because the "official" answer was posted there.

Answer (score 1):

Rather hackish, makes it into a dark green box:

javascript:$(".vote-accepted-on")[0].style.background="green";

Put this in a bookmarklet (create a new bookmark with this code as the location), and click it on every phy.SE answer page.

If you don't want to click the bookmarklet on every page, then you may want to set it up as a userscript. Copy this to notepad:

```
  // ==UserScript==
  // @match http://*physics.stackexchange.com/*
  // ==/UserScript==
 function with_jquery(f) {
     var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.type = "text/javascript";
     script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
     document.body.appendChild(script);
 };

 with_jquery(function($){
        var acceptbutton=$(".vote-accepted-on");
        if(acceptbutton.length!=0){
          acceptbutton[0].style.background="green";
        }

    });
```

Save as `prominentaccept.user.js` or something. Drag-drop this file into your browser. You will need to install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) on Firefox. On chrome, it will prompt you and work straight out-of-the-box on physics.SE and meta.physics.SE

Comment: If you want to try and make a better replacement for the accept button (this one puts a green box), replace the line `acceptbutton[0].style.background="green"` with `acceptbutton[0].style.background="url(URL_GOES_HERE)"`, using the url of a better image.

Comment: Any reason why someone doesn't just fix the problem???

Comment: @HotLicks: Well, SE Inc employees do roam around the metas, maybe they didn't notice this. I've brought this to their attention.