# "Accept" contrast draws a vacuum

Tags: bug, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The color difference between the “answered” checkmark and the “unanswered” one is barely discernable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/the-color-difference-between-the-answered-checkmark-and-the-unanswered-one-i)

It's virtually impossible (at least on my LCD laptop screen) to tell the difference between an "accepted" checkmark and an "unaccepted" one.