# Color scheme and the colorblind

Tags: discussion, design

I am not an active or knwoledgable user of SE Physics, but as person with a light form of color blindness (actually green/blue weakness), I wanted to bring this to Meta's attention:

The Color scheme, while certainly pleasing, relies heavily on subtle hues and I have difficulty in discerning these differences.
I just clicked the "accepted" button for an answer five times because I have been unable to see a change, only the ALT-Text told me.
This is an extreme example, but if it affects me (I hardly ever have problems with colors) I guess that users with a stronger form of color blindness will even be more challenged.

This could probably be fixed easly by not only changing hues, but also changing the brightness of the color. It would make for a far mor readable experienced for us spectrally challenged folks ;)

That's all I have to say. Have a good day!

PS: I found the old question, but I explicitly wanted to state that it is not only the Accept Button I'm having problems with

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Obviously even those normally color sensitive people who think of these things have a hard time judging exactly what will cause trouble for whom. The Stack Exchange web designer, Jin, will see this sooner or later and then we'll see how he wants to proceed. Also, I've attempted to alert Jin on the moderation chat channel.

Comment: Green blue weakness? If you'll pardon me for asking, which form of colorblindness do you have?

Comment: Evidently Jin subscribes to the RSS feed for [design] so I've added the tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1117/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I also noticed this problem and I dont think it is only a problem of color blindness. It is also related to the monitor used, since different viewing angle shows different color contrast. Often, I find that I unintentionally move my head down to view a higher contrast view. The current "color difference" is so weak to distinguish, particular for tick of accepting answer and the "favourite tag"

Comment: @BenBrocka: I'm not an native speaker so pardon me if that was unclear. I'm not having as many green receptors on my retina as a normal person does. This causes me to have problems in differenciating hues between green and blue. Where you could tell apart, say, 20 hues, I'd only be able to tell apart 10 (numbers are ballpark and for scale only).

Answer (score 16):

I have updated the accepted checkmark green color. The change will be rolled out to live server after our next production build (maybe after midnight EST or sometimes tomorrow).

Here's a preview:

[image: Check mark icon change]

I typically use [Sim Daltonism](http://michelf.ca/projects/sim-daltonism/), a color blind test app for OSX to make sure the colors show up well. I just tested the new green color using it, under both Protanopia and Deuteranopia settings. But from experience, it's not bullet proof, since it doesn't take account for discrepancies in people's monitor gamma settings.

Please let me know if the new green is better for you! thanks!

Comment: The new one looks much better to me (classical red-green colorblind).  I think in general it's best to have a significant difference in both color and intensity.

Comment: I find them significantly easier to tell apart. Thank you!